# EXTJS 6 Axis Time majorTickSteps

Tags: extjs, charts

I have created a report that is using an axes of type 'time'

It is pretty straight forward I think.

```
{
  type: 'time',
  position: 'bottom',
  fields: ['date'],
  dateFormat: 'Y-m-d',
  label: {
    rotate: {
      degrees: -45
   }
 }
}
```

It works fine, however there are too many steps on the axes, making it hard to see which steps are connected to the labels.
I just want to reduce the number of steps really, but this has proven a lot more difficult then I could imagine.
There is a setting called majorTickSteps that sounds usefull but I don't think it works with axis of type time?

Found this old fiddle to demonstrate.
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1995&view/editor

It looks the same for me when I try, a bunch of labels in the beginning and then one at the end.
Is there some way to do this?
To reduce the number of steps? Maybe some margin between the steps or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every axis have a `segmenter` that you can configure to manage steps. The `time` segmenter allow to define steps by unit (minute, hour, day, month...) and number of that units.

This is the updated fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3098&view/editor.

Comment: OK, thanks. It is a bit problematic since the dates will vary a lot, so I would have to set this segmenter dynamically depending on the input I guess. A shame really since the chart currently takes care of all this automatically, except for the steps.
But better than nothing, I will see what I can do.